# How do I get into the blocked-off room in World 5-2?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

In World 5-2, the level with the top-down perspective, there is a room with a sand floor, and a ? block in the middle of the room.

There is also a gate/mesh door in that room. I cannot get past it as Boomerang Mario, or regular Mario.

What do I have to do to get past that door?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that is the zelda room, you'll need to have the fire flower and light up the torches in the room. There is a fire flower in the very first room between the "!" question mark boxes.

[?]
[?]
[?]
 X  <--there's some fire power.
[?]

Hope that helps.. the formatting for posting that picture is a little off but you get the idea if your looking at the very first room of the world.

Comment: I would've never have though to find the fire flower there!